# python regex for string replacement

Tags: python, regex, string

I want to replace parts of a string that contains the following words "$%word$%"
I want to replace it with the value of a dictionary with the corresponding key equal to word.

In other words if I have a string: "blahblahblah $%word$% blablablabla $%car$%"
and a dictionary {word:'wassup', car:'toyota'}

The string would be "blahblahblah wassup blablablabla toyota"

How can you implement it in python, I was thinking about using string replacement and regex.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `re.sub` with a function as the *repl* parameter:

```
import re

text =  "blahblahblah $%word$% blablablabla $%car$%"
words = dict(word="wassup", car="toyota")

def replacement(match):
    try:
        return words[match.group(1)]  # Lookup replacement string
    except KeyError:
        return match.group(0)  # Return pattern unchanged

pattern = re.compile(r'\$%(\w+)\$%')
result = pattern.sub(replacement, text)
```

---

If you want to pass the replacement table at the time you use `re.sub`, use `functools.partial`:

```
import functools

def replacement(table, match):
    try:
        return table[match.group(1)]
    except:
        return match.group(0)

table = dict(...)
result = pattern.sub(functools.partial(replacement, table), text)
```

...or a class implementing `__call__`:

```
class Replacement(object):
    def __init__(self, table):
        self.table = table
    def __call__(self, match):
        try:
            return self.table[match.group(1)]
        except:
            return match.group(0)

 result = pattern.sub(Replacement(table), text)
```

Comment: What if the dictionary is created in another method? How would I implement replacement? I can't add arguments to replacement.

Comment: Very similar to this question;

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7182546/how-to-replace-the-nth-appearance-of-a-needle-in-a-haystack-python

Comment: @mabounassif - Let `replacement` take the dictionary as a parameter, then use `functools.partial()` to create a one-argument wrapper function that passes the dictionary. I'll update my answer to give an example.

Answer (score 1):

```
import re

text =  "blahblahblah $%word$% blablablabla $%car$%"
words = dict(word="wassup", car="toyota")

regx = re.compile('(\$%%(%s)\$%%)' % '|'.join(words.iterkeys()))

print regx.sub(lambda mat: words[mat.group(2)], text)
```

result

```
blahblahblah wassup blablablabla toyota
```

Answer (score 0):

The `re` module is the one you want.

You might want to reconsider your choice of delimiters, though.  `$%` might get problematic because `$` is a reserved character in regex.  Up to you though, just remember to use `'\\$'` or `r'\$'` (that's a raw string.  Very useful if you're doing regex stuff in python.) in your patterns.