# How to replace the Nth appearance of a needle in a haystack? (Python)

Tags: python, regex, replace

I am trying to replace the Nth appearance of a needle in a haystack.  I want to do this simply via re.sub(), but cannot seem to come up with an appropriate regex to solve this.  I am trying to adapt: http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/perl/cookbook/ch06_06.htm but am failing at spanning multilines, I suppose.

My current method is an iterative approach that finds the position of each occurrence from the beginning after each mutation.  This is pretty inefficient and I would like to get some input.  Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure, it is inefficient?

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/587345/python-regular-expression-matching-a-multiline-block-of-text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been struggling for a while with this, but I found a solution that I think is pretty pythonic:

```
>>> def nth_matcher(n, replacement):
...     def alternate(n):
...         i=0
...         while True:
...             i += 1
...             yield i%n == 0
...     gen = alternate(n)
...     def match(m):
...         replace = gen.next()
...         if replace:
...             return replacement
...         else:
...             return m.group(0)
...     return match
...     
... 
>>> re.sub("([0-9])", nth_matcher(3, "X"), "1234567890")
'12X45X78X0'
```

**EDIT**: the matcher consists of two parts:

1. the `alternate(n)` function. This returns a [generator](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/classes.html#generators) that returns an infinite sequence True/False, where every nth value is True. Think of it like `list(alternate(3)) == [False, False, True, False, False, True, False, ...]`.
2. The `match(m)` function. This is the function that gets passed to `re.sub`: it gets the next value in `alternate(n)` (`gen.next()`) and if it's `True` it replaces the matched value; otherwise, it keeps it unchanged (replaces it with itself).

I hope this is clear enough. If my explanation is hazy, please say so and I'll improve it.

Comment: This is interesting, although I am not quite sure how it is working.  I can see that from the result it replaces every third occurrence until the end of the haystack.  If I could understand the details of how this was working, I could add constraints to end after it successfully replaces an occurrence.

Would it be possible to add some explanation?  This looks like it could be the best answer.

Comment: I'd like to tie in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/231767/the-python-yield-keyword-explained to this answer. It explains generators very well.  I have a solid understanding of how this works thanks to your explanation and the other SO question.  Also, is this closure in action?

Comment: @bdilly yes. The `gen` variable is the trick: it's used inside `match`, but it is initialized in the outer scope

Answer (score 3):

I think you mean `re.sub`. You could pass a function and keep track of how often it was called so far:

```
def replaceNthWith(n, replacement):
    def replace(match, c=[0]):
        c[0] += 1
        return replacement if c[0] == n else match.group(0)
    return replace
```

Usage:

```
re.sub(pattern, replaceNthWith(n, replacement), str)
```

But this approach feels a bit hacky, maybe there are more elegant ways.

[**DEMO**](http://codepad.org/CfG6EAh2)

Comment: I looked at re.sub, but it didnt appear to have a way of replacing the Nth occurence, only all, or the first X ocurrences. So instead of making it work how I want, I thought it was simpler and clearer to take (to me) the obvious steps using findall/start&end etc..

Comment: @Matt: You are right, it does not have such a way built-in. With a function though you can get the desired effect. It might not be efficient though, as it actually replaces every occurrence (mostly with itself).

Answer (score 2):

Something like this regex should help you. Though I'm not sure how efficient it is:

```
#N=3   
re.sub(
  r'^((?:.*?mytexttoreplace){2}.*?)mytexttoreplace',
  '\1yourreplacementtext.', 
  'mystring',
  flags=re.DOTALL
)
```

The DOTALL flag is important.

Answer (score 0):

Could you do it using re.findall with MatchObject.start() and MatchObject.end()?

find all occurences of pattern in string with .findall, get indices of Nth occurrence with .start/.end, make new string with replacement value using the indices?

Answer (score 0):

If the pattern ("needle") or replacement is a complex regular expression, you can't assume anything. The function "nth_occurrence_sub" is what I came up with as a more general solution:

```
def nth_match_end(pattern, string, n, flags):
    for i, match_object in enumerate(re.finditer(pattern, string, flags)):
        if i + 1 == n:
            return match_object.end()


def nth_occurrence_sub(pattern, repl, string, n=0, flags=0):
    max_n = len(re.findall(pattern, string, flags))
    if abs(n) > max_n or n == 0:
        return string
    if n < 0:
        n = max_n + n + 1
    sub_n_times = re.sub(pattern, repl, string, n, flags)
    if n == 1:
        return sub_n_times
    nm1_end = nth_match_end(pattern, string, n - 1, flags)
    sub_nm1_times = re.sub(pattern, repl, string, n - 1, flags)
    sub_nm1_change = sub_nm1_times[:-1 * len(string[nm1_end:])]
    components = [
        string[:nm1_end],
        sub_n_times[len(sub_nm1_change):]
        ]
    return ''.join(components)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar function I wrote to do this.  I was trying to replicate SQL `REGEXP_REPLACE()` functionality.  I ended up with:

```
def sql_regexp_replace( txt, pattern, replacement='', position=1, occurrence=0, regexp_modifier='c'):
    class ReplWrapper(object):
        def __init__(self, replacement, occurrence):
            self.count = 0
            self.replacement = replacement
            self.occurrence = occurrence
        def repl(self, match):
            self.count += 1
            if self.occurrence == 0 or self.occurrence == self.count:
                return match.expand(self.replacement)
            else: 
                try:
                    return match.group(0)
                except IndexError:
                    return match.group(0)
    occurrence = 0 if occurrence < 0 else occurrence
    flags = regexp_flags(regexp_modifier)
    rx = re.compile(pattern, flags)
    replw = ReplWrapper(replacement, occurrence)
    return txt[0:position-1] + rx.sub(replw.repl, txt[position-1:])
```

One important note that I haven't seen mentioned is that you need to return `match.expand()` otherwise it won't expand the `\1` templates properly and will treat them as literals.

If you want this to work you'll need to handle the flags differently (or take it from [my github](https://github.com/mverrilli/python_snippets/blob/master/sql_functions.py#L3), it's simple to implement and you can dummy it for a test by setting it to `0` and ignoring my call to `regexp_flags()`).